# Issue with 'FirebaseUser' Future

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am having an issue implementing Google Sign in with Firebase in a new project saying the expression doesn't evaluate to a function. The code has worked in my other projects over the past year. Here is my code:

```
class FirebaseAuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn;

  FirebaseAuthService({FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth, GoogleSignIn googleSignin})
      : _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? FirebaseAuth.instance,
        _googleSignIn = googleSignin ?? GoogleSignIn();

  Account _userFromFirebase(User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return Account(
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoUrl: user.photoURL,
    );
  }

  Stream<Account> get onAuthStateChanged {
    return _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebase);
  }

  Future<Account> signInAnonymously() async {
    final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
    return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
  }

  Future<Account> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }

  Future<Account> currentUser() async {// The Issue is here in the Future<>
    final user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return _userFromFirebase(user);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to more clearly indicate where the problem is, and the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of `firebase_auth`(0.18.0+1), there is no `currentUser` function, and it does not return a `Future`. There were major **breaking** changes done to many of the FlutterFire packages that may have changed this syntax and you likely updated your packages without looking at the changelog for these breaking changes.

Getting the [`currentUser`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/currentUser.html) has now been changed to a getter and no longer returns a `Future`.

The `currentUser` function should be modified to the following:

```dart
Account currentUser() {
  final user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
  return _userFromFirebase(user);
}
```